# Is there a way to remove the titlebar for Silverlight out-of-browser apps

Tags: silverlight, out-of-browser, titlebar

I assume the window is owned by the sllauncher...so is there a way to remove its titlebar?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's possible in Silverlight 3, but in SL4 you should be able to customize the chrome of the window.
Here is a thread you might find interesting:
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/146039/325204.aspx

I am not sure if you will be allowed to remove the titlebar entirely though...

Comment: FYI, I believe you can remove the title bar or redefine it, at least according to http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/1789-silverlight-4-how-to-customize-oob-window.aspx.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. AFAIK, it's not supported until now (SL4 B1)

Comment: Just a clarification: It is *not* available in the current beta of SL4, but it will be in the final release. And probably also in beta 2 or whatever comes next.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you are from Silverlight team or not. I'm a Silverlight MVP and a part of Silverlight Insider team... I didn't hear any promise for that from Microsoft... but yes, I might be wrong..